# Angular Web Add in Office JS Excel Data Binding

Tags: javascript, excel, angular, typescript, office-js

I am trying to a load a table which has 160 Columns using angular as a web add in into my Excel Spread sheeet. I am able to create headers but when i try to do data binding excel doesn't work. I tried it with the basic sample code provided on microsoft website as well and that doesn't work too. I am using Anuglar 8.

```
  await Excel.run(async context => {

      const r = p.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();//+ 'FB' + (1 + this.loaddata.length)
      r.name = this.selectedName; //  this is working fine 

      const v = r.tables.add('A1:' + 'FB' + (1 + this.loaddata.length), true);
      v.name = this.selectedName;//  this is working fine 

      v.getHeaderRowRange().values =
        [[A,B,C,.... FB] // row headers are working fine ;


  this.tblBodyData.map(()=> [[this.loaddata[i].k.A..... t 
  this.loaddata[i].FB]]); // tblBodyData: any[] = [];

 // tried this this.tblBodyData.push([[this.loaddata[i].k.A..... 
 // this.loaddata[i].FB]]);


 //I am able to data inside display this.loaddata on a Html table on the web 
   side of the app

 v.rows.add(null,this.tblBodyData);
  // tried this as well v.getDataBodyRange().values = this.tblBodyData;




      v.getRange().format.autofitColumns();
      v.getRange().format.autofitRows();



      r.getUsedRange().getEntireColumn().format.autofitColumns();
      r.getUsedRange().getEntireRow().format.autofitRows();

       r.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
       r.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();

       if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApi", "1.5")) {
        r.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
        r.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();
      }
      r.activate();
      // }
      // return context.sync();
    }

    //  return context.sync();

    await context.sync();
  }
);
```

}

I also tried this

```
  const k = context.workbook;
  const y = k.worksheets.add('Welcome');
     //this works fine
  const expensesTable = y.tables.add('A1:D1', true /*hasHeaders*/ );

  expensesTable.name = 'ExpensesTable';
   //this works fine

  expensesTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [
     ['Date', 'Merchant', 'Category', 'Amount']
    ];
  //this works fine

  expensesTable.rows.add(null /*add at the end*/ , [
  ['1/1/2017', 'The Phone Company', 'Communications', '120'],
  ['1/2/2017', 'Northwind Electric Cars', 'Transportation', '142.33'],
  ['1/5/2017', 'Best For You Organics Company', 'Groceries', '27.9'],
  ['1/10/2017', 'Coho Vineyard', 'Restaurant', '33'],
  ['1/11/2017', 'Bellows College', 'Education', '350.1'],
  ['1/15/2017', 'Trey Research', 'Other', '135'],
  ['1/15/2017', 'Best For You Organics Company', 'Groceries', '97.88']
  ]); // this part doesnt work


  y.getUsedRange().getEntireColumn().format.autofitColumns();
  y.getUsedRange().getEntireRow().format.autofitRows();
  await context.sync();
  });
```

I tried attaching the debugger from my Visual Studio 2019 to Edge ,Explorer, Excel but it is not hitting the breakpoint I set in my VScode, Any Ideas on how to set this up . I am able to hit few breakpoints when i open my localhost:3000 in chrome dev tools but i am getting a 404 from Telemetryproxy and it is not hitting my component. I have tried this one as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-tables#import-json-data-into-a-table .

```
   Excel.run(function (context) {
   var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");

   var expensesTable = sheet.tables.add("A1:D1", true /*hasHeaders*/);
   expensesTable.name = "ExpensesTable";
   expensesTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [["Date", "Merchant", 
  "Category", "Amount"]];

   var transactions = [
   {
    "DATE": "1/1/2017",
    "MERCHANT": "The Phone Company",
    "CATEGORY": "Communications",
    "AMOUNT": "$120"
   },
   {
    "DATE": "1/1/2017",
    "MERCHANT": "Southridge Video",
    "CATEGORY": "Entertainment",
    "AMOUNT": "$40"
   }
   ];

   var newData = transactions.map(item =>
    [item.DATE, item.MERCHANT, item.CATEGORY, item.AMOUNT]);

   expensesTable.rows.add(null, newData);

   if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApi", "1.2")) {
    sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
    sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();
   }

   sheet.activate();

   return context.sync();
   }).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

After doing some research , i found that you can only debug using Visual Studio 2015, I am able to attach my Visual Studio to Iexplorer - Script/Task .. I am not able to hit breakpoints but i do see some Js code generated. I do see this error now "A table cannot overlap a range that contains a PivotTable report, query results, protected cells or another table." When i try to add new values to table.

Comment: Please provide details of "doesn't work" and please provide the entire `Excel.run` from your code.

Comment: Hi Rick Kirkham, thanks for the reply. I have updated the code

Comment: I still don't know what you mean when you say "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? Also, your code is hard to read because you don't use best practices in naming `const`s. JavaScript is case sensitive. Some of your code, like `Table.Rows.Add(null,[[//my json data converted into any []]]);` has the wrong casing on object/method names.

Comment: I did update the code,  I am not getting any error, the json data doesn't show up on the table which i created, Table headers are showing up and I am able to add sheets with custom name, but when i try to insert my json data, I am not seeing anything no error/ no data loaded on to the spread sheet..